# Do "Oracle Streams" have anything to do with the "Oracle Stream Class"?

Tags: oracle, terminology, oracle-streams

Oracle has a concept call ["Oracle Streams" which is extensively documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28321/toc.htm). Does this have any relation to the ["Stream Class"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lncpp/stream-class.html#GUID-9B333B43-7008-4514-BF03-F1339179E2C7). My assumption is no, and that they're entirely distinct but disambiguation would really help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Streams is (was*) a built-in framework in Oracle databases that is used for logical data replication between databases.

The OCI Stream class is not related to it.

*Oracle 18c is the last release with Oracle Streams. Oracle Streams will be desupported in Oracle 19c. [Terminal Release of Oracle Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/terminal-release-oracle-streams.html#GUID-A28764D7-EDD7-41CF-92DF-60A3FBDD949A). Streams became deprecated in favor of Oracle GoldenGate 5 years ago. Streams was free, no additional cost on top of the database license. GoldenGate must be licensed and it costs as much as Oracle Standard Edition.